# save PDF attachment with filename &domain name

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to run a macro to do follow steps:
- save PDF only attachment to hard drive
- save it with a revise name filename & domain name.
Here is the code I search from open source and mix it together. any help is appreciated. thanks

```vb
Public Sub Download_Attachments()

    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim olFolder_Inbox As Folder
    Dim olMail As MailItem
    Dim olAttachment As Attachment
    Dim strFolderPath As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strSenderAddress As String
    Dim strSenderDomain As String
    Dim fso As Object


    strFolderPath = "C:\"

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set olFolder_Inbox = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder


      Set olMail = Application.ActiveWindow.CurrentItem

'Get sender domain
      strSenderAddress = olMail.SenderEmailAddress
      strSenderDomain = Right(strSenderAddress, Len(strSenderAddress) - InStr(strSenderAddress, "@"))



    For Each olMail In olFolder_Inbox.Items

        If TypeName(olMail) = "MailItem" And olMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then


           For Each olAttachment In olMail.Attachments

                Select Case UCase(fso.GetExtensionName(olAttachment.FileName))

                    Case "PDF", "pdf"
                        olAttachment.SaveAsFile strFolderPath & strFileName


                    Case Else
                        'skip

                End Select

           Next olAttachment

        End If


    Next olMail

    Set olFolder_Inbox = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code retrieves the active folder in the Explorer window, not the Inbox one. Outlook can be started with any active folder, you can specify the folder name to the Outlook.exe file. To get the default folders (Inbox) you need to use the [NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm761)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder of the requested type for the current profile; for example, obtains the default Calendar folder for the user who is currently logged on. For example, the following sample code uses the `CurrentFolder` property to change the displayed folder to the user's default `Inbox` folder.

```
Sub ChangeCurrentFolder()  
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace  

 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
 Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 

End Sub
```

Then it is not really recommended to iterate over all items in the folder.

```
For Each olMail In olFolder_Inbox.Items
```

Instead, you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the Items class to get only items that correspond to your conditions. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Finally, the part you are interested in is the [SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Attachment.SaveAsFile) method of the `Attachment` class which saves the attachment to the specified path:

```
olAttachment.SaveAsFile strFolderPath & domainName & strFileName
```

Make sure a qualified file path is passed as a parameter. I'd recommend running the code under the debugger and see what values are passed.